# MATLAB: symbolic differentiate f with respect to x(t)?

Tags: matlab, symlink, symbolic-math, mupad

I have a function `f(x(t))=sin(x(t))` that I would like to differentiate in MATLAB sometimes with respect to `t`, sometimes with respect to `x(t)`. In MATLAB, I enter:

```
>> syms x(t);
>> f=sin(x(t));
>> diff(f,t)

ans =

cos(x(t))*diff(x(t), t)
```

However when I differentiate with respect to `x(t)` I get:

```
>> diff(f,x)
Error using sym/diff (line 26)
All arguments, except for the first one, must not be symbolic functions.
```

A workaround is to do:

```
>> syms temp;
>> subs(diff(subs(f,{x},{temp}),temp),{temp},{x})

ans =

cos(x(t))
```

However for *large functions* that I actually deal with in my code, `subs` is **very** slow - it's the bottleneck in my code. Surely there is a way to directly do `diff(f,x)`?! I mean the developers at MathWorks can't have just left such a huge tail hanging, right?

I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Documentation does tell you how to use multi-variable equations in `syms`, but indeed nothing about implicit functions. Strange.